Using @koumoul/vjsf to generate schema based forms in Vue3
How do I use the VJSF in vue 3 ? I am using vite as the build tool.
I tried the installation steps as per the documentation. However I am receiving an error from vite,
Forced re-optimization of dependencies
Failed to resolve dependency: ajv/dist/2019.js, present in 'optimizeDeps.include'
Failed to resolve dependency: ajv-i18n, present in 'optimizeDeps.include'
Failed to resolve dependency: ajv-errors, present in 'optimizeDeps.include'
I have added the configs related to VJSF commonJS deps in vite. Still the error persists.
Can some one help me with the correct usage of the package. Or please help me with alternatives to VJSF that is compatible with vue 3 and vuetify 3.

There are expected to be ajv and ajv-i18n deps installed in your project. It's not confirmed if it's so

I encounter error in dev mode (in production all ok):
Uncaught SyntaxError: import not found: fullFormats validate.js:1:10

After following instructions in chapter "CommonJS dependencies" https://koumoul-dev.github.io/vuetify-jsonschema-form/latest/getting-started I got error on page:
Uncaught SyntaxError: import not found: default resolve-refs.js:1:8

In dev console I had warnings:
Failed to resolve dependency: ajv/dist/2019.js, present in 'optimizeDeps.include'
Failed to resolve dependency: ajv-i18n, present in 'optimizeDeps.include'
Failed to resolve dependency: ajv-errors, present in 'optimizeDeps.include'

I found fix for that adding these dependencies manually:
npm i ajv
npm i ajv-errors
npm i ajv-i18n
npm i ajv-formats


Thanks for the response, in my case, i had all these dependencies installed. After a few debugging I found out the issue was due to the CSP. I had to set  "script-src": ["'self' 'unsafe-eval'"]

Don't know if this will solve your problem, but solved mine. As it says on the docs: https://koumoul-dev.github.io/vuetify-jsonschema-form/latest/getting-started # CommonJS dependencies:

Unfortunately some of the dependencies used by vjsf are published in the CommonJS format. This breaks homogeneity with the otherwise ESM modules of this library. You might need to inform your build system, for example with Vite:

But as it is on the docs didn't work for me, so I made mostly the same manually, on your vite file config (vite.config.ts);
optimizeDeps: {
  include: ['ajv', 'ajv-formats', 'ajv-i18n', 'debug'],
},
resolve: {
  alias: {
    '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
    'ajv-formats': 'ajv-formats/dist/index.js',
    'ajv-errors': 'ajv-errors/dist/index',
    'ajv/dist/2019.js': 'ajv/dist/2019.js'
  },
}

